# Redirect from parent controller

Tags: laravel

I'm implementing some Access Control Logic for a Laravel application. I'd like to redirect to a 'not authorised' page if the user is not authorised to view that resource.

I'm using controller/method logic for my urls.

I can redirect from the controller/method that is called, but to make my code more scalable, I'd like to check the ACL logic in a parent controller, maybe the Base_controller, and redirect from there, before the URI controller/method is accessed.

I have tried to add a redirect to a construct, or call another method in the construct that redirects, to no avail.

So, I'm wondering if this is possible, because 'Redirect::to' seems to only work in the controller/method specified in the url, and nowhere else - is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to 'return' the redirect. You can do this from anywhere:

```
return Redirect::to('login')
```

But you should run logic in filter:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->beforeFilter('acl');
}
```

Then in filters.php

```
Route::filter('acl', function()
{
    if ($something)
    {
          return Redirect::to('somewhere');
    }
});
```

Comment: return Redirect::to('login') doesn;t seem to work anywhere. I tested in the __construct() for a controller and it did not redirect.

Comment: is 'login' a valid uri? If its not, you probably have to redirect to the corresponding named route. Note that you have to create the route first before using the Redirect class. For example, you can create a named route loginPage and then do a named redirect, like Redirect::route('loginPage')